# Primefaces Wizard next button not working

Tags: css, jsf, templates, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to perform some operation with wizard but when I used wizard in my project with template Next button does not work. Template does not contain any .js file. But when i used wizard without template by using html simple code - it is working fine.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    template="./../templates/loggedinTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">View Dashboard</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="description">
        <meta name="description" content="Create Group" />
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="keywords">
        <meta name="keyword" content="Create Group" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="moduleDetails">
        <h:form>

            <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" />

            <p:wizard flowListener="#{groupWizardBean.onFlowProcess}">
                <p:tab id="createGroup" title="Add Group Details">
                    <p:panel header="Group Details">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5"
                            style="width:700px;"   columnClasses="label, value">


                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Group Name" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:inputText id="groupName" value="#{groupWizardBean.groupName}"
                                    required="true" validatorMessage="Required Group Name"
                                    requiredMessage="Please enter your Group Name"
                                    style="width: 280px;">

                                </p:inputText>

                            </p:column>


                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Group Description:" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:inputText id="groupDesc" value="#{groupWizardBean.groupDesc}"
                                    style="width: 280px;height:100px"></p:inputText>
                            </p:column>


                            <p:column colspan="2">


                            </p:column>


                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>


                <p:tab id="member" title="Team Members">
                    <p:panel header="Add Team Members">
                        <p:dataTable var="user" rowKey="#{user.userID}"
                            selection="#{groupWizardBean.selMemberList}"
                            value="#{groupWizardBean.activeUsersList}">

                            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />

                            <p:column headerText="Email Id">
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.emailId}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Name">
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.realName}" />
                            </p:column>


                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>


            </p:wizard>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

What will be issue of wizard not to work with template. can anyone tell me?